# Como passar um valor para próxima página com PHP

Tags: php, html, post, get

No código abaixo tento passar para próxima página o valor `NumeroCartao`. Porém a variável está vazia na página seguinte. Como conserto este erro?

INDEX.PHP

```
<label> Numero da Carteira: </label>  <span> <? echo $linha['NumeroCartao'];?> </span>
<div class="">
   <input class="numerocarteira" id="NumeroCartao" name="NumeroCartao" type="hidden" value="<?=$linha['NumeroCartao']; ?>" />
   <input class="" id="NumeroCartaoDis" name="NumeroCartaoDis" type="text" disabled="" value="<?=$linha['NumeroCartao']; ?>" />
</div>
</label>
```

CONSULTA.PHP

```
$numeroCartao = $_POST['NumeroCartao'];
echo "NUMERO CARTA0 {".$NumeroCartao."}";
```

Comment: Você pode postar o código que fica entre `<form>` e `</form>`?

Comment: O `echo $linha['NumeroCartao']` exibe o valor corretamente?

Comment: Não uso <form> uso ajax!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sobre método do *form*:

Ao enviar dados de um formulário em *PHP*, os métodos usuais são o `GET` e o `POST`. As variáveis enviadas com o `GET` vão no *URL* da requisição, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
http://example.com/consulta.php?NumeroCartao=2890127812781233
```

e devem ser recuperadas no *PHP* com `$_GET['NumeroCartao']`.

Já as enviadas com `POST`, vão no corpo da requisição, e não aparecem no *URL*. Estas devem ser recuperadas `$_POST['NumeroCartao']`.

Para o seu código, você precisa se certificar de estar usando o método `POST`

```
<form action="consulta.php" method="post">
   <label>Numero da Carteira:</label>  <span><?php echo $linha['NumeroCartao'];?></span>
   <div>
      <input class="numerocarteira" id="NumeroCartao" name="NumeroCartao" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $linha['NumeroCartao']; ?>" />
      <input id="NumeroCartaoDis" name="NumeroCartaoDis" type="text" disabled="" value="<?php echo $linha['NumeroCartao']; ?>" />
   </div>
</form>
```

### Outras considerações:

Não diretamente ligado ao form, mas pode aproveitar e usar aspas simples neste caso:

```
echo 'NUMERO CARTA0 {'.$NumeroCartao.'}';
```

Com aspas duplas, o caractere `{` tem uma função especial no *PHP* para interpretar variáveis, melhor sempre evitar ambiguidades.

Apesar de o *PHP* permitir este formato:

```
<?= $linha['NumeroCartao']; ?>
```

dê preferência para a versão longa sempre que puder:

```
<?php echo $linha['NumeroCartao']; ?>
```

Assim, sua aplicação ficará mais portátil caso um dia vá para um servidor em que as tags curtas `<?` estejam desabilitadas.