# Como não perder o preenchimento dos campos do formulário, após validação com PHP

Tags: php, html

Esta pergunta difere das perguntas já existentes:
[Como persistir/preencher os dados de um formulário via PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38898/como-persistir-preencher-os-dados-de-um-formul%c3%a1rio-via-php) e
[Como passar um valor para próxima página com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14373/como-passar-um-valor-para-pr%c3%b3xima-p%c3%a1gina-com-php)
pelo fato do meu formulário ter entre 50 e 100 campos, e por isso uma solução usando GET ou POST ser pouco prática ou mesmo inviável.

Apesar do meu formulário em produção tem uma grande  quantidade de campos, estou usando o código abaixo com apenas 2 campos pra simplificar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<form class="form" name="frmCadAcolhido" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="inserir" >

            <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" class="control" name="nome" required>

            <label class="control-label">CPF</label>
            <input type="text" class="control" name="cpf" required maxlength="11">

            <input type="submit" name="btnCadastar" value="Cadastrar">
 </form>
```

Quando o usuário clica no botão, o script em "insert.php" é submetido. Primeiramente, ele verifica se o CPF digitado pelo usuário já existe na tabela através de uma consulta ao banco MySQL. Caso o CPF não exista, é feito um INSERT dos campos na tabela. Mas caso o CPF já exista, ele exibe uma mensagem de erro e retorna ao formulário. Segue o código php:

```
include "Conexao.class.php";

$dados = $_POST;

if($dados['acao'] == 'inserir')
{
    $conn = new Conexao();
    $conn->conectaBase();

    $cpf = $dados['cpf'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn->link,"SELECT * FROM acolhidos WHERE cpf = '$cpf' ");

    $existecpf = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    // Se o número do CPF já existe na tabela ACOLHIDOS, retornar mensagem de erro.

    if ($existecpf != 0){
        echo "<script>alert('ERRO: CPF já existe no banco de dados.');</script>";
        echo "<script>history.go(-1)</script>";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO acolhidos
    (
    nome,
    cpf
    )
    VALUES
    (
    '$dados[nome]',
    '$dados[cpf]',
    )";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn->link, $sql);
    echo mysqli_error($conn->link);
}

$conn->desconecta();
```

Porém, quando o script retorna para o formulário html, o conteúdo de todos os campos do formulário aparece vazio.

Como eu poderia fazer para que, ao retornar para o formulário, os dados digitados pelo usuário continuem preenchidos?

O comando `echo "<script>history.go(-1)</script>";` volta para a página do formulário, mas com os campos vazios.

Comment: Utilize *session flash*

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, você se refere a PHP Flash Messages? como em https://mikeeverhart.net/php-flash-messages/

Comment: Pode ser, mas você pode implementar. Basta salvar o *POST* em uma [**session**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.examples.basic.php) no `insert.php` e depois de utiliza-las no *HTML*, é só destruir-las.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PHP, caso já tenha o CPF, faça o redirecionamento direto pelo php passando os dados por get

```
include "Conexao.class.php";

$dados = $_POST;

if($dados['acao'] == 'inserir')
{
    $conn = new Conexao();
    $conn->conectaBase();

    $cpf = $dados['cpf'];
    $nome = $dados['nome'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn->link,"SELECT * FROM acolhidos WHERE cpf = '$cpf' ");

    $existecpf = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    // Se o número do CPF já existe na tabela ACOLHIDOS, retornar mensagem de erro.

    if ($existecpf != 0){
        //redireciona a página para o html passando os dados por get
        header("location: ./caminho/do_formulario.html?cpf=$cpf&nome=$nome&mensagem=CPF%20já%20existe");
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO acolhidos
    (
    nome,
    cpf
    )
    VALUES
    (
    '$dados[nome]',
    '$dados[cpf]',
    )";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn->link, $sql);
    echo mysqli_error($conn->link);
}

$conn->desconecta();
```

E no HTML só mostrar os dados:

```
<form class="form" name="frmCadAcolhido" method="post" action="insert.php">
<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="inserir" >

    <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="control" name="nome" value="<?php echo $GET["nome"]; ?>" required>

    <label class="control-label">CPF</label>
    <input type="text" class="control" name="cpf" value="<?php echo $GET["cpf"]; ?>" required maxlength="11">

    <input type="submit" name="btnCadastar" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
<p>
    <?php echo $GET["mensagem"]; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: o problema é que meu formulário completo tem mais de 50 campos... neste caso, fica inviável enviar tudo por GET?

Comment: Acredito então que você deva diminuir esses campos, por exemplo, tenho um projeto em que o usuaruio digita apenas nome e telefone e faz uma busca, se não tiver ninguém, ele pode adicionar os outros campos, coloque na primeira tela apenas os campos essenciais depois ele preenche os demais.

Comment: Mas caso precise dos 50 campos, uma opção seria criar uma sessão com esses valores, redirecionar para o formulário, exibir os dados (guardados na sessão), e destruir a mesma, outra opção é, como dito na outra resposta, fazer requisuições assíncronas com AJAX

Comment: gostei da sua sugestão! Farei um 'pré-formulário' apenas com os campos nome, datanasc e cpf, e após validar que o cadastro realmente não existe no bd, abrirei um formulário com os demais campos.

Comment: Isso também aumenta a esperiência do usuário, imagina preencher 50 campos e no final não adiantar nada, seria muito frustante

Answer (score -1):

Você está enviando uma requisição via form para o arquivo insert.php, porém a página que possui o formulário é HTML e ao enviar as informações a página é atualizada e neste caso é como uma página nova, ou seja, os campos do formulário estarão sem preenchimento.
Seria melhor você utilizar outros meios para fazer o que deseja.

Caso você queira pode utilizar JQuery conforme o exemplo que deixei abaixo:

```
<form class="form" id="frmCadAcolhido" name="frmCadAcolhido" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="acao" name="acao" value="inserir" />
    <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="control" id="nome" name="nome" required />
    <label class="control-label">CPF</label>
    <input type="text" class="control" id="cpf" name="cpf" required maxlength="11" />
    <input type="button" id="btnCadastrar" name="btnCadastrar" value="Cadastrar" />
    <input type="reset" id="btnLimpar" name="btnLimpar" value="Limpar" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#frmCadAcolhido #btnCadastrar').on('click',enviaForm);
    });
    function enviaForm(){
    var acao = $('#frmCadAcolhido #acao'),
    nome = $('#frmCadAcolhido #nome'),
    cpf = $('#frmCadAcolhido #cpf'),
    btn = $('#frmCadAcolhido #btnCadastrar');
    btn.prop({'disabled':true}); // ajuda a evitar duplo click e várias requisições
    if(acao.val()=='inserir'){
        if(nome.val()==undefined || nome.val()==null || nome.val()==''){
            alert('Favor preencher o campo');
            nome.focus();
            btn.prop({'disabled':false});
            return false;
        }
        else if(cpf.val()==undefined || cpf.val()==null || cpf.val()==''){
            alert('Favor preencher o campo');
            cpf.focus();
            btn.prop({'disabled':false});
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $.post('insert.php',
                {acao : "\'" + acao.val() + "\'",nome: "\'" + nome.val() + "\'",cpf: "\'" + cpf.val() + "\'"},
                function(data){
                    alert(data); //Trate o resultado como quiser
                    btn.prop({'disabled':false});
                    return false; // impede a atualização da página e mantém as informações nos campos
                }
            );
        }   
    }else{ alert('Erro ao enviar form');btn.prop({'disabled':false});return false;}
}
</script>
```

Troquei o input "submit" para "button" e adicionei "id" em todos os input's.

Comment: antes de sinalizar negativo, poste sua resposta como ajuda, só negativar não ajuda, ao menos coloque sua justificativa ao negativar.

Comment: Nunca comece uma resposta dizendo 'use jQuery'. A propósito, não fui eu quem negativei, a solução pode ser válida mas deveria ser independente de biblioteca.

Comment: @epx alterei o termo "use jQuery", porém você pode postar uma solução independente da biblioteca?

Comment: @WilsonRosaGomes, esta solução também funcionará se estivermos trabalhando com 50 ou mais campos no formulário?

Comment: Sim, e você pode fazer validação nos campos, vou melhorar o exemplo e colocar uma validação